# Show/Hide div using javascript without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that shows /hides multiple independent divs on a page. The problem is that when you click to show a div, no matter where on the page, it will automatically focus on the first div. Is there a way to focus on the div that was displayed?

here is the javascript:

```
   function toggleOptions(e) {
        var ele = e;
        var text = e.parentElement.querySelector('.toggleOptions')

    if(text.style.display == "none") {
        //ele.style.display = "none";
        text.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "TESTING";
        ele.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
    else {
        text.style.display = "none";
        //text.innerHTML = "Hide GPS";
        ele.innerHTML = "show";
    }

    return false;
     }
```

here is the html:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleOptions(this);" style="display:block;">
        show
     </a>
      <div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">
        ITEM 1 OPTIONS
     </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleOptions(this);" style="display:block;">
        show
     </a>
      <div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">
        ITEM 2 OPTIONS
     </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleOptions(this);" style="display:block;">
        show
     </a>
      <div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">
        ITEM 3 OPTIONS
     </div>
</div>
```

here is a jfiddle of the work http://jsfiddle.net/YE6XZ/1/

Comment: This must be browser specific. With firefox, the focus is on the `div` clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your show links a class, like:

```
<a class="show" href="#" onclick="toggleOptions(this);" style="display:block;">show</a>
```

Then add this to your jQuery:

```
$('a.show').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The default action for a bookmark anchor (`href="#"`) is to jump to the top of the page. This would prevent that. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YE6XZ/5/)**

An alternative, jQuery-less method would be to change your onclicks to:

```
onclick="return toggleOptions(this);"
```

As you are already returning false. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YE6XZ/3/)**

Comment: If you didn't notice, there is no jQuery in his example, and it is not even included in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @NickMitchinson - yes, of course I noticed that. However the question is tagged with it.

Comment: @NickMitchinson true, but the OP did tag his question with the `jQuery` tag, therefore j08691 is allowed to come up with a jQuery answer I suppose.

Comment: @NickMitchinson - I've updated my answer with a jQuery-less solution as well.

Comment: you can use jquery with javascript ;) so it works great! thanks!

Comment: Fair enough, I missed the jquery tag. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could also use the `.focus()` method to focus on a given element. In your example:

```
function toggleOptions(e) {
    var ele = e;
    var text = e.parentElement.querySelector('.toggleOptions')

    if(text.style.display == "none") {
        //ele.style.display = "none";
        text.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "TESTING";
        text.focus(); //This should give focus to the newly shown text element
        ele.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
    else {
        text.style.display = "none";
        //text.innerHTML = "Hide GPS";
        ele.innerHTML = "show";
    }

    return false;
}
```

Unless I am misunderstanding what you are looking to do....

Answer (score 0):

use javascript:void(0) in href. Use javascript functions to show or hide using id

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Show</a>
```