# Hide/ Show div based on URL that loads without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website where the menu is such that, the new page/url loads with the  page reloading.

I am trying to hide a div using the following code- this works when the page reloads but does not work when the url changes without page reload.

```
$(function(){
    if (window.location.hash == "#home") {
        $('.axiosnext-arrow').hide();
    } else {
        $('.axiosnext-arrow').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This might help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395244/show-hide-div-using-javascript-without-page-refresh)

Comment: code in question only works when you reload page .you need to use this code when you change URL on specific event

Comment: @NishitMaheta so how do i make it work on change or url

Comment: @user38208 see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use hashchange on the window global it will work, see example below

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    if (window.location.hash == "#home") {
       $('.axiosnext-arrow').hide();
    } else {
       $('.axiosnext-arrow').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The onhashchange event occurs when there has been changes to the anchor part (begins with a '#' symbol) of the current URL.

**[hashchange Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onhashchange.asp%20%20%20%20%20window.addEventListener(%22hashchange%22,%20hashChangeFunction);)**

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashChangeFunction);

function hashChangeFunction() {
  if (window.location.hash == "#home") {
    $('.axiosnext-arrow').hide();
  } else {
    $('.axiosnext-arrow').show();
  }
}
```

Using JQuery

```
$(function(){
  if (window.location.hash == "#home") {
    $('.axiosnext-arrow').hide();
  } else {
    $('.axiosnext-arrow').show();
  }

  $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
     if (window.location.hash == "#home") {
       $('.axiosnext-arrow').hide();
     } else {
       $('.axiosnext-arrow').show();
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign your function to `onhashchange` event. Your javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
  if (window.location.hash == "#home") {
    $('.axiosnext-arrow').hide();
  } else {
    $('.axiosnext-arrow').show();
  }
}
```

Then, on your HTML, do this:

```
<body onhashchange="myFunction()">
```

To know more about `onhashchange` event, take a look at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onhashchange.asp)